# Is the converse of this subspace statement true?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

If two vectors are in a subspace, then so is their vector sum.  Is the converse of this statement true?

Comment: No. $(1,1) + (1,-1)$ lies in the subspace generated by $(1,0)$, but the two original vectors obviously don't.

Answer (score 1):

No. Take $\mathbb{R}^2$ and consider the subpace $S:= \{(x,x) : x \in \mathbb{R} \}$. Then $(1,0) + (0,1) \in S$ but neither summand lies in $S$.

Comment: Great minds think alike :)

Comment: omg this is scary...

Comment: Yes it is lmao!

Answer (score 0):

No. $$(1,0)+(0,1)=(1,1)\in \text{span}\big((1,1)\big)$$ but neither are in the subspace themselves. $$(1,0),(0,1)\notin \text{span}\big((1,1)\big)$$

Comment: Great minds think alike ;)

Comment: That's uncanny. I said exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Given an arbitrary vector space $V\neq\{0\}$, take the subspace $\{0\}$, then for any nonzero $v \in V$, we have $v, -v \not\in \{0\}$ but $v+ -v \in \{0\}$.